# Material ui and reactjs, <Textfield/> with ref : doesn't work

Tags: reactjs, textfield, material-ui

I have a problem to recover the value of input with  when I transform an input into TextField

That's the code that works :

```
<form onSubmit={(e) => this.goToNextStep(e)}>
  <input type="text" className="form-control" placeholder="Name" pattern="[A-Za-z-]{1,}" required ref={(input) => {this.nameInput = input}} />
  <RaisedButton label="GO" color="primary" primary={true} type="submit" />
</form>
```

And the goToNextStep function :

```
goToNextStep = event{
event.preventDefault;
const name = this.nameInput.value;
console.log(name);
}
```

So with this, when I submit, I get the name back.

But with  when I submit, I don't get the name back.

That's the code that doesn't works :

```
<form onSubmit={(e) => this.goToNextStep(e)}>
  <TextField ref={(input) => {this.nameInput = input}} floatingLabelText="Name" pattern="[A-Za-z-]{1,}" required /> 
  <RaisedButton label="GO" color="primary" primary={true} type="submit" />
</form>
```

Do you know why it doesn't work ?
How to  make it good ?

Thanks for help :)

Answer (score 0):

You got `ref` to a component instance, not a real `<input>`

```
<TextField ref={(input) => {this.nameInput = input}} floatingLabelText="Name" pattern="[A-Za-z-]{1,}" required />
```

Read more about [it in docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html#exposing-dom-refs-to-parent-components). Unfortunately, I don't see a way to pass ref callback [to TextField component](http://www.material-ui.com/#/components/text-field).

Comment: Ok thanks and you are agree with me, to make an input we are forced to use <TextField />
And if I write const name = this.nameInput.input.value it's work, why ?